# Unresolved reference: toByteString

Tags: android, build.gradle

I am using an [SDK](https://developer.trustwallet.com/wallet-core/integration-guide/android-guide) , which requires data in "ByteString".

When I am trying to convert `BigInteger` to `toByteString`, Its giving me an error message.

```
BigInteger("d693a400", 16).toByteString()
```

> Unresolved reference: toByteString

I tried to include `protobuf` plugin,but still the error is there.

**Project Level - Build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

**App Level - Build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id "com.google.protobuf" version "0.8.15"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I added the dependency `implementation "com.trustwallet:wallet-core:0.12.31"` I could then use ByteString from `com.google.protobuf`

I checked the repo and found these extensions https://github.com/trustwallet/wallet-core/blob/05375deb1b4b45d491b59ca775aa43e9e9a39b11/android/app/src/main/java/com/trustwallet/core/app/utils/Extensions.kt#L17 which is an extension on String.

So I looked in their actual example and found out that they use a custom function there:

```
private fun BigInteger.toByteString(): ByteString {
    return ByteString.copyFrom(this.toByteArray())
}
```

Source: https://github.com/trustwallet/wallet-core/blob/05375deb1b4b45d491b59ca775aa43e9e9a39b11/samples/android/app/src/main/java/com/trust/walletcore/example/MainActivity.kt#L115

Comment: Note that I never used this SDK ever. But sometimes doing a search on repo code can help.